# how to hide one icon on click of other icon on actionbar android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two icons on actionbar what i want is when i click on edit icon update icon gets hide and when i click on update button edit icon gets hide also when i press back button my activity crash

```
enter code here
```

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
return when (item.itemId) {

```
       R.id.edit_icon -> {
            name.setEnabled(true);
            phone.setEnabled(true);
            name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            phone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            cameraIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            return true
        }

        R.id.update_icon -> {

return true
        }
```

Comment: And where do you initialize your `cameraIcon`? Try to do it in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

Comment: basically i don't know how to handle menu items in kotlin can you tell me how to hide one icon on click of other. cameraIcon is image which i am showing on click of edit icon

Comment: Add more context. Where do you initialize name, phone - what is it?